# What is this Ktav?

Tags: history, aleph-bet-letters, sefer-torah

[image]

My son sent me this picture of an old voweled text, probably around 10-12 centuries CE. What stands out, is that the letter He is connected and Chet is flat on the left side.

Is this a fragment of a Torah scroll or a Chumash? What kind of Ktav is it?

Comment: Hei dangling in the middle with chet being connected on the end used to be a very common way of writing. It's discussed in the rishonim.

Comment: If you look at both the Aleppo or the Leningrad Codex, you can see this type of ה

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a screenshot from the 10th-century [Damascus Pentateuch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damascus_Pentateuch). See the full page [here](https://www.loc.gov/resource/gdcwdl.wdl_11364/?sp=389). The writing is fairly typical for that era.

Comment: +1. Can you add a source or two from the Rishonim that discuss Heh looking like Chet?

Comment: @Harel13 Famous Shut Tashbetz if I'm not mistaken. See too the gemara in menachot about safra davkana debei rav. see yd 276 about how/if to correct a hei that does touch, and even haezer 126:48 that a touching hei is kosher bemakom iggun.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you! (15)

Comment: @Harel13 oops it's rivash not rashbatz. Got my head in Algeria I guess. See too radvaz https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%22%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%91%22%D7%96/%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%95

Comment: All good (luckily, I haven't gotten around yet to poring over the sources).

Comment: There seems to be a consistent difference between the heh and chet (not the usual one) the top left corner sticks out more by the chet